# Delete selected row dgv

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a problem on deleting a data from datagridview. I don't know why on how to fix it. So, after I press the delete button and select the yes button on dialogresult. I got this error; "Error: Invalid column name EMP". Help me guys. Thanks id advance!!

**Codes:**

```
Public Sub deleteEmployee()
        employeesView.btnDelete.Text = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete the selected employee?", "WARNING: DELETION OF EMPLOYEE!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        If employeesView.btnDelete.Text = DialogResult.Yes Then
            employeesView.btnDelete.Text = "Delete"
            Try
                dbConnection()
                Dim employee_number As String = employeesView.EmployeeDGV.SelectedRows(0).Cells("employee_number").Value
                delete_query = "DELETE FROM tblemployee_information WHERE employee_number = " & employee_number
                command = New SqlCommand
                With command
                    .Connection = connection
                    .CommandText = delete_query
                    result = .ExecuteNonQuery()
                    If result = 0 Then
                        MsgBox("Error in deleting employee!")
                    Else
                        MsgBox("Successfully deleted the selected employee!")
                    End If
                End With
            Catch ex As SqlException
                MsgBox("Error : " + ex.Message)
            Finally
                connection.Close()
                command.Dispose()
                retrieveEmployees()
            End Try
        Else
            employeesView.btnDelete.Text = "Delete"
        End If
    End Sub
```

**Button:**

```
Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
        deleteEmployee()
    End Sub
```

**Table**

```
--Table Structure for Employees Information
CREATE TABLE tblemployee_information (
    employee_number varchar(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    employee_first_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    employee_middle_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    employee_last_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    employee_contact varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    employee_address varchar(200) NOT NULL  
);

--Table Structure for Employees Account
CREATE TABLE tblemployee_account (
    employee_account_id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    employee_email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    employee_username varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    employee_password varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    employee_role varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    employee_number varchar(50) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tblemployee_information(employee_number) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: Code seems good... try to search where have you used this word as column name 'EMP'...you may be able to get a clue.

Comment: What is the value of `employee_number` when you debug? Side note: Seems like you should also include some kind of check here to confirm the user has selected a valid row before running the Delete also. `Using` on your connection & command with a parameterized query should also be used here.

Comment: I think you can miss single quotation mark. It should be: DELETE FROM tblemployee_information WHERE employee_number = '    " & employee_number & " '  ".

Comment: You desperately need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. Building up a string like this is NOT a good way of doing this. It is wide open to sql injection. Fix this before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Parameters, you will avoid lots of problems, both small and huge. Here you have a string for a PK but you are treating it as a number. You don't have to worry about it if you use Parameters correctly.

```
Dim cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Connection String")
Dim delete_query As String = "DELETE FROM tblemployee_information WHERE employee_number = @empNumber;"
Dim Command = New SqlCommand With {
      .Connection = cn,
      .CommandType = CommandType.Text,
      .CommandText = delete_query}
Command.Parameters.Add("@empNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = employee_number
Dim Result As Integer = Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```